# Mail rules with Script Warning message

Tags: mail.app, applescript, mail-rules

I am getting so fed up with this:

[image]

It is too real not to make the mistake in a moment when I am not fully on alert (and to be hones that stresses me out), and I want to use my powerful Mac to protect me from killing myself.

So I want my Mac mail to do some work for me, more than just be dumb and to dump all emails in the junk.

I want to eliminate me in the process.

I want to make a Rule in mail that:

1-Analises each email coming from "my"? bank, or containing the name of it.
Regardless of real or not.

I want a script to display a large warning on the screen for that email to remind me that that email can be a Scam, so I do not accidentally open it.

How do I do that in Mail.app.

Yes I know I should not open attachments and reply to emails like it, but it is 100% looking like real emails not to make the mistake eventually when not being on alert all the time. So Mac, do some intelligent work and save me from myself.

In this case the `alerts@notify.wellsfargo.com` is 100% legitimate From address, so someone tell me how the hell do they do fake that.

Comment: There is no way to be ensured of the sender as it is a value send with the mail. the `mailx` command for example allows to define the senders mail address. That's how a buddy of me send me a mail as `billgates@microsoft.com`.

Comment: So that makes the use of Junk filter based on "From" useless. A another reason for my request.

Comment: Do you even have an account with Wells Fargo? You could just move all mail from Wells Fargo to the Trash if not.

Comment: @bmike, why do you still keep that around?

Answer (score 1):

Since anyone can fake the From field, the use of junk or Rule filter has become uselles.

So I have tentatively solved my issue with a

Rule in Mail:

[image]

And Apple Script to at least Warn me:

```
set alertResult to display alert ¬
    "Buscar, this could be a SCAM." buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} as warning ¬
    default button "Cancel" cancel button "Cancel" giving up after 10
```

[image]